# format '_' expects argument of type '__' but argument 2 has type '__'. C programming, I am a beginner

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

This is the structure I have defined with the following members:

```
struct id{
    char name[32];
    int age;
    float iq;
};
```

This are print statements in one of the fucntions:

```
printf("Enter your age: ");
scanf("%d",p->age);

printf("Enter your iq: ");
scanf("%f",p->iq);
```

The issue is, the code compiles with 2 warning(s):

```
format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 
'int'.
format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 
'double'.
```

The output on Build/Run, returns:

```
segmentation failed(core dumped).
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Also can someone mentor me, remotely? To become a genius at C-Programming ? :p**

This is the entire source code of my program, cant understand why it wont work, the way I want it to. I found a workaround but I want to understand the concept behind the warning message(s).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/*declaring struct as global item*/
struct id{
    char name[32];
    int age;
    float iq;
};

/*prototyping*/
struct id *fAllocate(void);
void fFetch(struct id *p);
void fShow(struct id *p);

int main()
{
    struct id *author; //declaring the var of_type struct id

    /*allocate struct - fAllocate()_function*/
    author = fAllocate();

    /*fetch structure/populate - fFetch()_function*/
    fFetch(author);

    /*show struct - fShow()_function*/
    fShow(author);

    return 0;
}
/*fAllocate()_function*/
struct id *fAllocate(void){
    struct id *p;
    p = (struct id *)malloc(sizeof(struct id));
    if(p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Unavailable!");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return(p);
    }
    return;
}
/*fFetch()_fucntion*/
void fFetch(struct id *p){
    //declaring var to store scanf values
    /*
    char *n;
    int i;
    float f;
    */
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",p->name //&n);
    //strcpy(p->name,n);

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",p->age //&i);
    //p->age = i;

    printf("Enter your iq: ");
    scanf("%f",p->iq //&f);
    //p->iq = f;

    return;
}
/*fShow()_function*/
void fShow(struct id *p){
    printf("Author %s is %d years old!\n",
           p->name,
           p->age);
    printf("%s has an iq of %.2f!\n",
           p->name,
           p->iq);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You might like to have look into `scanf()`'s documentation.

Comment: You forgot to take the addresses of the relevant objects.

Comment: @alk thanks What you said worked, however i had to use &(p->age), parenthesis around the pointer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` needs to be able to store the data it scans in. So it expects addresses, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &p->age);
```

and

```
scanf("%f", &p->iq);
```

[POSIX documentation is here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html)